# How can I get the id of the object I´ve just inserted into a mysql database in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I´m trying to retrieve the id of the object I've just introduced into the database but it doesn't work (I always get an exception) and it´s not beacause of the query, aparently it works fine. I've tried other ways I found on-line and none of them worked. This is the code I´m using (C# and the database is MySql)

```
conn.Open();
command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = //here it goes the insert command which works perfectly
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Last object's id is retrieved
command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT last_insert_id() AS id)";
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
 reader.Read();
 MessageBox.Show(reader["id"].ToString());
}
conn.Close();
```

Any help would be appreciated even it's not the final solution :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I always get an exception" Can you please post the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: You could have a column named logged_date with the default value of current_time.
So in this case you requirement can be easily accomplished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add it after the insert statement.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT ...  ; select last_insert_id();";
```

and then use this to get the result:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Adding it to the end is better than calling the second statement in a separate command, but still subject to retrieving the wrong id in high traffic situations.

Comment: @ChrisGessler: No, it's not. See comment to my answer.

Comment: Depends on the application. I agree with this if multiple inserts can happen at the same time.

Comment: Oops... apparently the MySql ODBC driver doesn't support this.

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra parenthesis at the end of the query.

Change this

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT last_insert_id() AS id)";
```

to:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT last_insert_id() AS id";
```

And then you are reading past the first record to the second record, but there is only one record.

Change this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
 reader.Read();
 MessageBox.Show(reader["id"].ToString());
}
```

to:

```
reader.Read();
MessageBox.Show(reader["id"].ToString());
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Executing two statements without a transaction may result in retrieving the last id for a different insert, especially in a multi-user environment

Comment: @ChrisGessler: You are mistaken. The value of `last_insert_id()` is not affected by other users. "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Comment: "LAST_INSERT_ID() (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a column. "
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Well, there you have it.  The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wrote:

```
SELECT last_insert_id() AS id)
```

You have to remove that final `)`, it's causing a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

remove  `reader.Read();` from while loop

use `executescalar` instead of `executereader`.

```
int no = convert.toint32( command.ExecuteScalar( "SELECT last_insert_id() AS id"));
```